# Can someone explain Method of Lagrangian multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Can someone explain Method of Lagrangian multipliers to a beginner? I need some knowledge about solving problems using this method. If someone can provide the basic details in a simple manner along with some neat(and discreet) example(s), that would be of immense assistance.

Comment: lol Google :D ${{{}}}$

Comment: See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176705/understanding-the-concept-behind-the-lagrangian-multiplier

Comment: Paul's Online Notes [ http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx ] are a pretty good introduction, since he includes some worked examples.  You could even search this site for examples. (I even wrote a page about the idea of this method: http://recklessreckoner.blogspot.com/search/label/Lagrange%20multipliers .)